# Ruby on rails - activeadmin - batch_action default text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, action, activeadmin

is there a way to set a default input value for batch_actions?

e.g. I have 3 inputs fields, I want to save these in a session, but I couldn't figure out, how to set a default text in my form.
 form -> { 'Bla' :text } ...
do you guys know how I can set a default value?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you are using generic form like [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#a-generic-search-form), set like `<%= text_field_tag(:q, 'default text') %>`

Comment: The batch action form is a jQuery modal dialog, not a Rails form.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, no. If you are really serious you can customize modal_dialog.js and batch_actions/controller.rb, for example https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/3965/files